# Flutter android how to get readable firebase crashlytics report?

Tags: android, flutter, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

We have obfuscated our code on the Android side, and since then, we can't get a readable crashlytics report. I tried so many options, but nothing has worked so far.

[image]

I tried many different solutions.

First: I enabled/disabled `mappingFileUploadEnabled` & uploaded with and without `debugging_file.zip` to google play store using `.aab` file.

I created `debugging_file.zip` using three files under `build/app/intermediates/flutter/prodRelease/` which are `arm64-v8a`, `armeabi-v7a` and `x86_64`.

Second: I enabled `mappingFileUploadEnabled` file & uploaded with and without `debugging_file.zip` to google play store using `.aab` file.

I created `debugging_file.zip` using three files under `build/app/intermediates/merged_native_libs/prodRelease/out/lib` which are `arm64-v8a`, `armeabi-v7a` and `x86_64`.

I am using :

```
flutter: 2.10.0
dart: 2.16.0
firebase_core: ^1.4.0
firebase_crashlytics: ^2.4.5
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
```

proguard:

```
-keep class androidx.lifecycle.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    <fields>;
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable        # Keep file names and line numbers.
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception  # Optional: Keep custom exceptions.
```

gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Have any idea to encounter the problem?

Answer (score 3):

after many researchers and multiple tries to get a solution for this problem
this is as far as i have gone.
you can only deobfuscate dart code manually using this command

```
flutter symbolize -i <stack trace file> -d /out/android/app.android-arm64.symbols
```

check this link for more info
https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/obfuscate

the steps i followed to solve it is as follows:
1-create file error.txt
2-copy paste stacktrace from crashlytics where numbers are inlined.

ex :

```
  #08 abs 0 virt 00000000002ccc63 _kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x114473 (.java)
  #09 abs 0 virt 00000000002ccae3 _kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x1142f3 (.java)
  #10 abs 0 virt 000000000059d687 _kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x3e4e97 (.java)
```

3-add before every line 2 to 4 spaces.
4-remove (.java) if exist.

5-run this command in flutter terminal

flutter symbolize -i error.txt -d build/app/outputs/symbols/app.android-arm64.symbols